# How can i make a div that slides up to reveal a page without completely hiding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I want to be able to click and shrink to the top ~10% of a page. I have code similar to this where one DIV should cover everything, then the second DIV would have the content for the page:

```
<div id="cover">Optimized the javascript so that all code is based on jQuery.
</div>

<div id="content" style="height:300px;" class="hide" >Optimized the javascript so that all code is based on jQuery.
</div>
```

This is a partial example of what I want to do:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/M3WGw/98/)

The problem with this is that the slideUp() function seems to completely hide the "cover" DIV rather than shrink it to part of it's size. The other problem I have is that the background doesn't scale with the DIV. I would like the background image to shrink to a reasonable size in the cover DIV. Is this possible? In my example JSFiddle, the white space should have the "cover" DIV, and a smaller version of the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `slideToggle();` is actually supposed to hide or show an element completely due the fact that you're not supposed to hide or show it with the element you're hiding / showing.

So to solve your problem I've created an extra div that will hide or show the element giving it the appearence of only partly hiding the element. You can find the fiddle here:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/M3WGw/100/)

I've also scaled the background for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery's `animate()` for this and replace `background-attachment:fixed` with `background-size: 8em;`

Tweak this part depending on the size of your divs `{ "height": "30%","background-size": "6em" }`

```js
$(function () {
    $('#cover').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({ "height": "30%","background-size": "6em" }, 400, function () {
            $(this).next().show();
        });
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.hide {
    display: none
}
.show {
}
#cover {
    background-color: black;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    background-size: 8em;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVX13.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}


#content {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:30%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cover">Optimized the javascript so that all code is based on jQuery.</div>
<div id="content" class="hide">Optimized the javascript so that all code is based on jQuery.</div>
```